VMware shared folder: files created by guest are not visible on host
Windows 10 running vmware player with Ubuntu 24 guest.
I have a shared folder setup to always be enabled.
The command I used to mount (currently) it is:
sudo vmhgfs-fuse -o uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),allow_other .host:/folderName /mnt/folderName

Any files I created on the guest since last mount will appear again but:

None of the files created by host are visible on the guest.
None of the files created on guest can be seen on the host.

I have read and tried most of the answers on Stack Exchange already.

It's the same as dual-booting: Disabling Windows' Fast Startup "feature is a MUST.

why would that affect shared folders in vmware player?

I had to install a new Ubuntu guest OS from scratch making sure not to install any updates during setup.
Once setup was complete I shut down the guest before adding the shared folders in the settings and booting it up again.
Then I edited /etc/fuse.conf and added/uncommented:
user_allow_other

Then I ran the command to mount all shares at once without picking a specific one:
/usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /home/<username>/shares -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other

I also tried doing the same thing on the original system and it made no difference. It was as if something caused the mount to exist in some void outside of the host and guest file systems, with files suddenly existing again when the mount was added back.
I still don't know what caused the original issue.
